# Mysql_real_escape_string() Warning Confusion

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string($dbc, "string");
```

Produces the warning:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object 
given in **...**
```

So even when I give the function what seem to be obviously string objects it's not seeing them as strings.

What's going on here?

Comment: order is going on out here. first string please.

Comment: Looking at my question I realized my mistake was I meant to use the mysqli_real_escape_string() function not mysql.

echo mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, "string"); works like a charm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` just takes a string for an argument. That's it.

`$string = mysql_real_escape_string('string')`

If you want to specify the link identifier, it is the optional second argument:

`$string = mysql_real_escape_string('string', $dbc)`

Answer (score 2):

Check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). The parameters go the other way around (connection is optional).

```
mysql_real_escape_string('string', $conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing two parameters to it like the following?

```
mysql_real_escape_string($dbc, "string");
```

Try this, it should work.

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string($dbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we use `mysql_real_escape_string` is when we dealing with an SQL statement, where we have to loop through each field, some of which are empty and some are not strings. **The error says the function expects a string**, meaning some fields are not strings, to avoid this warning you have to perform a check:

```
if (!empty($dbc) && is_string($dbc))
    echo mysql_real_escape_string($dbc, "string");
```