# Codeigniter showing error: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am working on a project where it has a simple enquiry form. The model code is as follows:

```
 public function insenqm($name, $email, $enqtype, $comments) {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'enqtype' => $enqtype,
            'comments' => $comments
        );
        $this->db->insert('enquiry', $data);
    }
```

First I thought that the data is not entering the model function `insenqm`, but it is entering the function and not getting inserted in the database. And instead showing error as follows:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 314




A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/webtrees123/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:186)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 543
```

When I googled for the error, it showed that the keyword `mysql` has been depricated and suggested to use `mysqli`. However, it is working perfectly on my local machine, but showing this error on server. You can see the error by visiting [this link](http://shivharelab.com/) and the filling the enquiry form at the end of the web page.

Does anyone have any suggestion on why the error is coming? If yes please reply to this question.
All positive suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: refere this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637215/mysql-real-escape-string-warning-confusion may it helps

Comment: @bluto the code is something like this, `$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str, $this->conn_id);`. On entire page, there was no `$dbc`

Comment: what is `$this->conn_id`? remove it and try

Comment: it's code on line no. 315 in the file mysql_driver.php where it is showing error

Comment: second param is optional, remove and try..

Comment: @bluto removing second parameter removed the error too, but now it is not inserting the form data into the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error occur in Code Igniter and saw it multiple times in my logs file after I upgrade to PHP 5.4 on my server.

This error is a typical thing that happens when you upgrade to PHP 5.4 to get the new fun stuff.
Hopefully you have your error logging activated so you can see it.

This error is due to the following function in the mysql driver.
Assuming Code Igniter: 2.2.6, the latest version:

```
function escape_str($str, $like = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($str))
    {
        foreach ($str as $key => $val)
        {
            $str[$key] = $this->escape_str($val, $like);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str, $this->conn_id);

    // escape LIKE condition wildcards
    if ($like === TRUE)
    {
        $str = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\\_'), $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

It will also occur if you use the mysqli driver (a setup in your database), so using the other driver will not solve it, because there is a similar function.

The error results from the fact that `$this->escape_str()` is called without a connection to mysql, so the error occurs, because $this->conn_id is not a resource.

There is also a similar error when using an older version of CI that uses `mysql_escape_string($string)`

Because I'm using PHP 5.4 and that error would not be a warning, it would be 8192 E_DEPRECATED!
That would give you some hint as to what version of CI 2 you are using. 
In any event the solution is the same:

In any case, the error can be fixed with this:

Here's what I changed this function to

```
function escape_str($str, $like = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($str))
    {
        foreach ($str as $key => $val)
        {
            $str[$key] = $this->escape_str($val, $like);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    if (is_resource($this->conn_id)) {
                $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str, $this->conn_id);
                //log_message('error', 'is_resource is true');
            } else {
                //log_message('error', 'string to convert is '.$str);                    
                $str = addslashes($str);

            }

    // escape LIKE condition wildcards
    if ($like === TRUE)
    {
        $str = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\\_'), $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

You'll notice I've left some log_message() calls in there when I did my testing to see what this function was escaping, which I've commented out above.

The latest code from Version of CI 2 will still not contain this fix.
CI 2 is not under active development.

Lastly, I'd like to point out this post for reference:

http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62431.html
mentions that there is a character set MySQL injection technique which may warrant upgrade to 3.0.

Not sure if that is the case in this fix, though.

Someone else could look into how this function is being called and fix the caller, rather than this function.

Here's the link to the [mysql driver code in version 2.2.3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/88cb5d9304cf302c2a4f7bd55731682cd43c99a2/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php) on github.